# subview is not added immediately (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

When the return button on the keyboard for a textfield is tapped I want to add a UIView, then connect to a website with `NSURlConnection sendsynchronousrequest` and I have the code in that order
But when I run in the simulator (I can't run on device) the connection is run first then the subview is added (ie the opposite of the order of the code)
Why is this and how can stop it, because I want the view to added, then the connection done and then the view removed.

Comment: why are you using a synchronous request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subview is being added, but views are drawn by the runloop. By making a synchronous request on the main thread, you are blocking the runloop, so the view won't be drawn until after the request completes. Do the request asynchronously, either by using the async API or by doing a synchronous request in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Many actions happen on the run loop, rather than in the order you code. If you really want to code the way you have, then performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: with a delay of 0 *might* work to trigger your NSURlConnection (you will need to move that code to a method).

As JK suggests, an asynchronous request might solve it anyway, and improve the UI. I'm a great fan of ASIHPPTRequest library, which makes async trivial.